# Find weighting values of a set of matrices so that the weighted average of them is close to a target matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices

I have a set of $n$ matrices:

$A = \left \{A_{1},A_{2},...,A_{n} \right \}$

and a target matrix $B$

I want to find weighting values:

$w =  \left \{ {w_{1}, w_{2}, ..., w_{n}} \right \}$

such that $w$ is minimizing equation $F$

$F = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}w_{i}}{n} - B$

note that all of those matrices have the same dimension

*===edit===*

in other words, I want $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}w_{i}}{n}$ to be as close as possible to $B$

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite each matrix as a long column vector, i.e., rewrite

```
   1  2
   3  4
  -2  6
```

as

```
   1  
   3  
  -2  
   2
   4
   6
```

Make them the columns of a matrix $M$. Do the same for $B$, making a column vector $b$. Now you're trying to minimize 
$$
\| Mw - b \|^2.
$$
The optimal solution is 
$$
w = M^{\dagger} b
$$
where the dagger indicates the pseudoinverse of $M$.

The formula for the pseudoinverse depends on whether the number of $A$ matrices $n$ is less than or greater than the number $k$ of entries in each matrix (i.e., whether you're solving an overconstrained or underconstrained problem).